# How to retrieve data from firebase and compare the data with string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not very used to Javascript code and firebase.

So, in firebase I have one parent node where I need to get the data from. This parent has child where each child has two kind of value in it (refer to the image)

[image]

Firstly I need to compare if my "Tanda" value equals to "ada kebakaran". If it's equal, then it start to retrieve the value on "kode".

this "kode" is use as reference to get more data in another parent node.

so far my code like this

```
function getdata(data){
firebase.database().ref("sensor").on('value', function(snapshot)){
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot))
  {
    var sensor = childSnapshot.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(sensor);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
      var k = keys[i];
      var tanda = sensor[k].tanda;
      if(tanda && "ada kebakaran"){
        //get the "kode" here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
firebase.database().ref("sensor").on('value', function(snapshot)){
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot))
  {
    var sensor = childSnapshot.val();
    var tanda  = sensor["tanda_kebakaran"];
      if(tanda == "ada kebakaran"){
        //get the "kode" here
        var kode = sensor.kode;
       }
    });
```

Add a reference to node `sensor` then iterate using `forEach()`, `childSnapshot.val()` will contain all the data under `sensor`.. Then you can access `tanda_kebakaran` value using bracket notation, and compare it.

Comment: yes. I doesn't retrieve the kode. I add console log to see if it's retrieve anything and none.

Comment: Is it entering the if?

Comment: i think it's not even retrieving data from the sensor. I checked on Console.log. It has my manually test variable but when I put inside the snapshot, it doesn't appear.

Comment: what does console.log(childSnapshot.val()); give you?

Comment: nothing came out. It didn't retrieve anything from childsnapshot

Comment: so I change the childsnapshot into using different variable and it work

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if I understood the question differently.
From what I understood, here's the code.

```
admin.firestore().collection("sensor").get().then((data) => {
    let finalData = [];
    data.forEach((doc) => {
        if(doc.tanda_kebakaran === "1")
            finalData.push({
                kode: doc.kode,
                tanda_kebakaran: doc.tanda_kebakaran
            });
    })
})
```

the finalData array should have the data you need.

Comment: i use realtime database this time. But it can be use for those who use firestore

Comment: Nice. Glad I helped. Yes the functionality stays the same.